# Approximation of two segmented linear regression

Tags: approximation, linear-regression

Is there any function that can approximate a two segmented linear regression? Suppose you have two linear regressions [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh8xm.png)

$y=0.1760x+2.4305\ \left\{x<77.6615\right\}$

$y=0.3011x-7.2865\ \left\{x\ge77.6615\right\}$

What single/continuous function can approximate x vs y relationship here? A function with 3 unknown parameters is preferable since I have only 4 points to fit.

Note: Interpolation or piecewise regression is not desired.

Comment: What is wrong with using a function that can be described by piecewise linear functions (like any linear spline interpolation does)?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch The two equation in the question are already piecewise linear functions. This is not what I want.

Comment: This question is really broad... You can start interpolating with polynomials or [trigonometric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_interpolation); or you can convolute your current function with [some smoothening kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier#Smoothing_property).....

Comment: Do you want a function that is infinitely differentiable at all points?

Answer (score 1):

If you want an infinitely differentiable function, translate the piecewise function so that the point where the two lines meet is at the origin. Then rotate the two lines clockwise around the origin so that one of them has a slope of $0$ and is on the left side of the y-axis (ie $x<0$). The other line should have a positive slope. Let the new slope of the other line be $s$. This means that one line is of the form $y = 0 \hspace{1 mm}\{x\le0\}$ and the other is $y = sx\hspace{1 mm}\{x > 0\}$. This new piecewise function can be approximated by $$y = \frac{1}{t} \ln(1+e^{tsx})$$

where $t$ is a positive number. The higher it is, the more accurate the function will be. Finally, rotate this function counterclockwise the same angle as before and translate it back.

Edit: This assumes the piecewise function is only two linear parts, is continuous, and the angle between the two linear segments is greater than $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: this function will have its elbow at 0. However the problem in the question has the elbow at [77.6615, 16.098]. Can you please clarify "rotate this function counterclockwise the same angle as before and translate it back"?

Comment: Step 1: translate the function so that its elbow is at $(0,0)$, so translate it left $77.6615$ and down $16.098$. Step 2: rotate it $\theta$ so that one side of the piecewise function has a slope of $0$. Step 3: follow the steps in the answer to get an approximation. Step 4: rotate the approximation $-\theta$. Step 5: translate it right $77.615$, up $16.098$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to approximate this discontinuous function in the same way that one might try to approximate any singularity function? Such as a ramp function or unit step function. Anyway, in this case you would stick to Fourier analysis, and you could approximate the function as an infinite sum of sines and cosines.

Comment: Except that the piecewise linear function is continuous :D

Comment: I meant to imply that it's not continuously differentiable